# How do I get my header to be responsive on all media?

Tags: css, wordpress

I already input width: 100% but it wont respond on anything. How do I get the header to respond on all browsers and ipads, phones, etc?

```
.head-wrap {
background: url(http://envisionmediallc.com/prodigy/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/We-are-prodigy-dumbell-weight.jpg) top no-repeat;
margin: 0;
height: 480px;
width: 100%;
}

.site-header {
background: url(http://envisionmediallc.com/prodigy/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Prodigy-Performance-we-are-prodigies4.png) no-repeat;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 420px;  
}

.site-header .wrap {
padding: 16px 0;
padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us relevant CSS code?

Comment: You should post code, instead of a link.  That way if the site goes down, the question will still be relevant to future SO users.

Comment: Using percentages on widths makes them relative to the known parent width only. The header is changing size with the browser, but that won't make the images scale down in size.

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Apparently you want to resize the background images in the header. Try playing with `background-size` property of `site-header` and `head-wrap`. Although you'll still need to add few media queries to resize the containers.

Comment: Are you referring to how the navbar elements spill out of the background when the window narrows? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the `background-size` style of the header to `100%;`  You may be dealing with some browser compatibility issues (see here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

You could also remove the `background-image` property, and fill the content with plain `img` elements, with absolute positioning, then set those img elements to be width: 100%;

Your div is also constrained to a height of 420px which is going to screw things up.  Set a max-height of 420px, and a `height` of auto (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

You'll probably have to make your two background overlapping background images the same size (since the dimensions are different they might have different ratios of width/height), and use some media queries to clean things up, though, to make it work 100%.